# erlang list filter question

Tags: list, filter, erlang

I have list - Sep1:

```
[
   ....
   ["Message-ID", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"],
   ["To", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"]
   ...
]
```

I try get element where first item = Message_ID for example:

```
lists:filter(fun(Y) -> (lists:nth(1,lists:nth(1,Y)) =:= "Message-ID") end, Sep1).
```

But i get error:

```
 exception error: no function clause matching lists:nth(1,[])

 in function  utils:'-parse_to/1-fun-1-'/1

 in call from lists:'-filter/2-lc$^0/1-0-'/2
```

But if i:

```
io:format(lists:nth(1,lists:nth(1,Sep1))).
> Message-ID
```

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: `lists:filter` calls the fun for every element in the list. Your code below just passes the whole list to `lists:nth`.

Comment: Theb how can i filter my list by first element each of list?

Comment: I suspect that you have another problem somewhere.  When I copy your `Sep1` and your `lists:filter` call into my Erlang shell, I get `[]` - not the right answer, of course, but different from the error you are getting.  Are you sure that you pasted your `Sep1` correctly?

Answer (score 5):

It's better to change representation to `[{Key, Value}, ...]` so you can use [lists:key*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3) functions, [proplists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) module, or convert it to [dict](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html) with [dict:from_list/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html#from_list-1).

But if you still want to use [lists:filter/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) you can filter list of lists by first element as following:

```
lists:filter(fun ([K | _]) -> K =:= "Message-ID" end, ListOfLists).
```

If you want to extract tails of lists which first element match with "Message-ID" you can use [list comprehensions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77064):

```
[Tail || ["Message-ID" | Tail] <- ListOfLists].
```

Comment: This fails if one element of the initial list is an empty list.

Comment: lists:key* functions and the lists:filter example works as expected with 3 element tuples and 3 element lists correspondingly

Comment: `fun ([K | _]) -> K =:= ExpectedValue; (_) -> false end` will work with any type of elements. But shouldn't you check your input data first?

Comment: Also, you could directly pattern match, i.e. `fun (["Message-ID" | _]) -> true; (_) -> false end`.

Comment: Yes, if second clause is used (as in the comment above) but it doesn't work with the original example. Actually I don't like examples in comments because anything can match, but you must know your data instead.

Comment: I will second to change the representation to `[{atom(), term()}]`. It will be way easier to work with in the long run. Another option is to create a record with all the mandatory entries and then have a properties key with the optional ones, but that is mostly a question of style.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use two nested `lists:nth` calls?

`lists:filter(fun(Y) -> lists:nth(1, Y) =:= "Message-ID" end, Sep1)` works for me and returns a list containing the elements you want (lists where the first element is `"Message-ID"`). Just pattern match on that list to get the element you want, e.g. if you want only one such element you can do:

```
case lists:filter(fun(Y) -> lists:nth(1, Y) =:= "Message-ID" end, Sep1) of
  [Result] -> % do something with it;
  [] -> % no such element found
end
```

Comment: To downvoter: When you downvote, please leave a comment explaining what you find false and/or misleading...

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is this:

```
[B || [A,B|_] <- L, A =:= "Message-ID"].
```

This does not assume any length of the nested lists:

It will return a list of the second elements of all inner lists whose first element is "Message-ID"

If you are sure there is only one "Message-ID" and want to throw an error otherwise:

```
[X] = [B || [A,B|_] <- L, A =:= "Message-ID"].
```

If you only want the first one (still throwing error when there is none):

```
[X|_] = [B || [A,B|_] <- L, A =:= "Message-ID"].
```

To understand what this code does I recommend reading [official Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html) about list comprehensions and the Learn You Some Erlang-chapter about the same topic: [List Comprehensions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your list contains only elements each of them with 2 elements, you could use lists comprehension doing something like this:

```
1> L = [["Message-ID","AAAAAAAA"],["To","BBBBBBBBBBB"]].
[["Message-ID","AAAAAAAA"],["To","BBBBBBBBBBB"]]
2> [[A,B]||[A,B] <- L, A =:= "Message-ID"].
[["Message-ID","AAAAAAAA"]]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, There are not 2 elements in the list.

Comment: His code only supposes that the insider lists have 2 elements

Comment: -1: This assumes that the inner lists contain two elements, in which case there is no reason to use lists in the first place.

Comment: And please use `=:=` in the comparison, using `==`for no good reason is bad example.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I've missed that, as usually I'm using '=:=' and totally agree that using "==" in erlang is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own filter (which doesn't care about the number of the elements):

```
    filter(List) -> filter(List,[]).

    filter([],Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
    filter([[]|Tail],Acc) -> filter(Tail,Acc);
    filter([[H|T]|Tail],Acc) ->
      case H =:= "Message-ID" of
        true -> filter(Tail,[[H|T]|Acc]);
        _ -> filter(Tail,Acc)
      end.
```

Comment: I'd probably define it on the already built-in: `my_filter(F, L) -> lists:filter(fun(["Message-ID"|T]) -> F(T); (_) -> false end, L).` or something such.